# You cannot invalidate the SPRequest object while it's in use

Tags: 2013, visual-web-part

Server Error when updating a list.

> You cannot invalidate the SPRequest object while it's in use

Here is my code:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
         web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

         SPList spList = web.Lists.TryGetList(UserListName);

         SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
         query.Query = @"<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Author' LookupId='TRUE'/><Value Type='Integer'>" + currUser.ID + @"</Value></Eq></Where>";

         SPListItemCollection MyDashboard = spList.GetItems(query);
    }
}
```

I believe it's crashing on this line:

```
spList.GetItems(query);
```

Also, this works the first time. Anytime after it does not. Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: is there a `query` variable?

Comment: Did you try getting web object directly form spcontext. That way you don't need to dispose it.